# FOSTwitterBundle error

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I installed FOSTwitterBundle using this tutorial [here](http://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSTwitterBundle) ,but I have an issue about how to save informations in my database of every user logged using his twitter account ?

Edit :

now I have this error :

```
ErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Skeleton\PanelBundle\Security\User\Provider\TwitterUserProvider::__construct() must be an instance of FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager, instance of FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager given, called in /var/www/skeleton/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1678 and defined in /var/www/skeleton/src/Skeleton/PanelBundle/Security/User/Provider/TwitterUserProvider.php line 34
```

here is my config.yml :

```
services:
    my.twitter.user:
        class: Skeleton\PanelBundle\Security\User\Provider\TwitterUserProvider
        arguments:
            twitter_oauth: "@fos_twitter.api"
            userManager: "@fos_user.user_manager"
            validator: "@validator"
            session: "@session"
```

and security.yml :

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:

    my_fos_twitter_provider:
        id: my.twitter.user 

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    public:
        pattern:  /
        fos_twitter:
            login_path: /twitter/login
            check_path: /twitter/login_check
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_twitter_provider

        anonymous: ~
```

Really I hate this bundle, i spend almost all day to information account in User Table in database!

==> all problems is in the service `my.twitter.user`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I must change this `use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager;` by this `use FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager;`

Also change this `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session` by `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session`